# select all with where using alias

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  birthdate DATE
);

INSERT INTO test (id, name, birthdate) VALUES (1, 'jhon', '1975-12-12');
INSERT INTO test (id, name, birthdate) VALUES (2, 'doe', '1994-12-12');
```

And tried to query like this:

```
select * 
from (
    select extract(year from age(birthdate)) as age from test
) d
where d.age >= 24
```

It works for the most part. What I wanted was to be able to query using `WHERE` on the `age`alias. The thing is that I needed to *"encapsulate"* it in another query as I read here in the forum already that I can't use `WHERE` in aliases unless using like this.

The problem: it's returning only `age`, even adding `select *` it's not returning the other fields, what am I doing wrong?

Here if you want to see running live: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qA8znjMzm4NR9wdCo5pssX/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also express this using a lateral join, which can be convenient particularly when there are multiple dependencies:

```
select * 
from test cross join lateral
     (values (extract(year from age(birthdate)))
     ) v(age) 
where v.age >= 24;
```

Comment: It's actually the best answer, I managed to handle this one better using Laravel actually with the `crossJoin`

Answer (score 3):

> it's returning only the age, even adding `select *` it's not returning the other fields

Then, `SELECT *` in the subquery too:

```
select * 
from (
    select t.*, extract(year from age(birthdate)) as age from test t
) d
where d.age >= 24
```

Or just drop the subquery and repeat the expression:

```
select t.*, extract(year from age(birthdate)) as age
from test t
where extract(year from age(birthdate)) >= 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is effectively `SELECT * FROM d...` (obviously I've removed the bit where you define d, to make the point). Since `d` only contains one field - age - then that's all you can return when selecting from d.

You would need to add all the other fields to the definition of `d` as well:

```
select * FROM
  (SELECT *, extract(year from age(birthdate)) as age from test) d
where d.age >= 24
```

Answer (score 0):

This case is when a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html) is helpful:

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT *, extract(year from age(birthdate)) as age 
  FROM test
)  
SELECT id, name, birthdate 
FROM cte
WHERE age >= 24
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qA8znjMzm4NR9wdCo5pssX/1).

Answer (score 0):

postgres doesn't allow column aliases in the where clause, if you need it in the where clause just use a copy of the column expression.

```
select extract(year from age(birthdate)) as age from test
where extract(year from age(birthdate)) >= 24;
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a more elegant solution.  No extra functions and give you both the result you want and will execute faster.

```
Declare  @test table (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  birthdate DATE
);

INSERT INTO @test (id, name, birthdate) VALUES (1, 'jhon', '1975-12-12');
INSERT INTO @test (id, name, birthdate) VALUES (2, 'doe', '1994-09-22');
INSERT INTO @test (id, name, birthdate) VALUES (3, 'billy', '1994-09-25');
INSERT INTO @test (id, name, birthdate) VALUES (3, 'bob', '1995-09-30');

/* For age accounting for leap years and no extra functions */

select name,birthdate
,  year(getdate())-year(birthdate)
 - case when dateadd(yyyy,year(getdate())-year(birthdate),birthdate) > getdate() then 1 else 0 end as Age
from @test
where year(getdate())-year(birthdate)
 - case when dateadd(yyyy,year(getdate())-year(birthdate),birthdate) > getdate() then 1 else 0 end >=24
go

/* Same data but using an inline table. */

Declare  @test table (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  birthdate DATE
);

INSERT INTO @test (id, name, birthdate) VALUES (1, 'jhon', '1975-12-12');
INSERT INTO @test (id, name, birthdate) VALUES (2, 'doe', '1994-09-22');
INSERT INTO @test (id, name, birthdate) VALUES (3, 'billy', '1994-09-25');
INSERT INTO @test (id, name, birthdate) VALUES (3, 'bob', '1995-09-30');

/* For age accounting for leap years and no extra functions */
select *
from (
    select name,birthdate
    ,  year(getdate())-year(birthdate)
     - case when dateadd(yyyy,year(getdate())-year(birthdate),birthdate) > getdate() then 1 else 0 end as Age
    from @test
) d
where d.Age>=24
```